# Joining tables on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a little problem - since im not very experienced in SQL - about joining the same table on multiple values. Imagine there is table 1 (called Strings):

```
id     value
1      value1
2      value2
```

and then there is table 2 (called Maps):

```
id     name     description
1      1        2
```

so name is reference into the Strings table, as is description. Without the second field referencing the Strings table it would be no problem, id just do an inner join on Strings.id = Maps.name. But now id like to obtain the actual string also for description. What would be the best approach for a SELECT that returns me both? Right now it looks like this:

```
SELECT Maps.id, Strings.value AS mapName FROM Maps INNER JOIN Strings ON Strings.id = Maps.name;
```

But that obviously only covers one of the localized names. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two joins to the same table:

```
SELECT m.id, sname.value AS mapName, sdesc.value as description
FROM Maps m INNER JOIN
     Strings sname
     ON sname.id = m.name INNER JOIN
     Strings desc
     ON sdesc.id = m.description;
```

Note the use of table aliases to distinguish between the two tables.

Comment: That was the first idea i was thinking about. Usually it wont be more than 3-4 localized names in a table, so would you recommend using a multiple join approach? Or are there other approaches that could fit my use case?

Comment: @Cromon . . . A separate join for each name would be appropriate for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to get a single value from another table, you can use subqueries to do these lookups:

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT value FROM Strings WHERE id = Maps.name) AS name,
       (SELECT value FROM Strings WHERE id = Maps.description) AS description
FROM Maps
```